# What value pull up resistors does the MPU9250 use?

Tags: resistors, accelerometer, pullup, gyro, imu

Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.invensense.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/PS-MPU-9250A-01-v1.1.pdf)

On page 32, the datasheet says "The MPU-9250 always operates as a slave device when communicating to the system processor, which thus
acts as the master. **SDA and SCL lines typically need pull-up resistors to VDD**. The maximum bus speed is
400 kHz."

There's no information about what value pull up resistors to use. Doing a quick search on google for mpu9250 schematics I see this schematic
[image]

It uses 10k resistors as pull ups. My question is whether this is accurate, and more importantly can I settle for 4.7k resistors since those are what I have lying around?

Comment: It's not the MPU9250 which determines this, but I2C in general.  10K may work, but sounds a bit high.  Something in the range of 2.2K - 4.7K is typical, so you could use one 4.7K resistor per line, or even put a parallel pair on each.

Comment: @Stratton thank you this answers my question. If 10k is too high, why does every schematic I've seen so far use it?

Comment: Laziness. At least it's not using the internal pull-ups of an Arduino, which are typically 3-5x bigger...

Comment: 10K is not *always* too weak.  It depends on the circuit loads and the needs - see the link.